# Is there a list of the paths used to include third party libraries that are shipped with SAP UI5?

Tags: jquery, sapui5, libraries

I'm trying to implement some drag and drop functionality in a UI5 app and I want to make it work with mobile devices so I'm using jQuery Touch Punch. I'm currently getting it from a CDN but I want to use the one shipped as part of UI5:

Snippet showing 3rd party libraries shipped with UI5:

[image]

but I can't for the life of me find the path to use to include it in the define or jQuery require statements. I've searched here, on SAP's help website and OpenUI5's GitHub with no joy.

Is there a list of paths for the libraries buried somewhere that I've missed or is there another way of working it out? It seems daft to provide the libraries and not give the information you need to use them but I'm coming up blank so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is no sign of touch-punch library usage in the OpenUI5 source at github. And as far as I can see the licensing popup window just shows a predefined constant list of 3rd party libraries.

Looking at the touch-punch source I can see that this is just a small patch which does not have a "public" interface, so you probably just add the single file available [here](https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/blob/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js) to your project and load it somewhere by **define** function and it should work.

Comment: Cheers, I was hoping to avoid having to do that but it looks like you're right and I that might have to be the way I go

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can directly look in the github source folders: [OpenUI5 Third Party libraries](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/tree/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/thirdparty)

What may be also helpful for you is the following tutorial on how to implement drag and drop in UI5: [Drag and drop between two SAPUI5 UI elements](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/08/21/how-to-use-drag-and-drop-between-two-sapui5-ui-elements/)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - I did end up check the github source and, as slkorolev says in his answer, it wasn't in there. Doesn't look like it's a thing sadly!